Adding multiple email addresses to advanced find in Dynamics 365
I need to update a field for several email addresses in Dynamics 365. I don't have coding experience or SQL access, but I’ve been using the Advanced Find option.
Is there a way to input multiple email addresses in the search field to show all matching records? I’ve read that a semi-colon should work, but it didn’t.
Any simple advice would be appreciated!
  <condition attribute="emailaddress1" operator="like" value="%emailaddress%" />
</filter>


Have you tried using the pipe | character between the email addresses?

if you are using Advance find you can put multiple filter using the same field, just group them using the OR. Select your filters the click the "Group OR" button from the command bar. You can then download the fetch xml query and see the result.
